# Generating random sequence in tensorflow with another tensor as seed

Tags: python, tensorflow, random, random-seed, hashlib

I have a use-case where I need to generate a sequence of random integers given an input integer. There are many ways to do this in python. The one I am currently using is as follows:

```
import hashlib
def nextRandom(seed, length, maxval):
    md5 = hashlib.md5(str(hash(seed)).encode('utf-8'))
    for k in range(length):
        md5.update(str(k).encode('utf-8'))
        yield int(md5.hexdigest(), 16) % maxval

seed = 12345
length = 10
maxval = 1000
for randInt in nextRandom(seed, length, maxval):
    print(randInt)
```

This ensures that the generated sequence is fixed given a `seed` value.

Now, I need to a similar functionality in tensorflow where `seed` comes as a tensor and the returned sequence should also be tensor.

I checked this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21974) in tensorflow github page, but couldn't find a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution with [`tf.contrib.stateless`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/stateless) module:

```
import tensorflow as tf

seed = tf.random_uniform(shape=[2], dtype=tf.int64, maxval=1000000)
x = tf.contrib.stateless.stateless_random_uniform(shape=(1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, seed=seed)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(x))
```

Note that, the `stateless` module does not support integers unless in [`stateless_multinomial`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/stateless/stateless_multinomial) case.

Comment: Thanks Amir.
I was able to use `stateless_multinomial` for the task as follows:

`tf.squeeze(tf.contrib.stateless.stateless_multinomial((1.0/maxval)*tf.ones(shape=(1,maxval)), num_samples=tf.convert_to_tensor(length), seed=tf.convert_to_tensor((seed,1))))`